# Stuck OpenShift Application

Tags: tomcat7, openshift

My application hang up. Because of that I wanted to delete the application but it's not possible. OpenShift just shows me: "Unable to perform action on app object. Another operation is already running" when I want to delete the application from the web interface.

`Unable to perform action on app object. Another operation is already running.`

When I check the status of my application then it is unknown. It shows "unknown" for my Tomcat server and also for my database server.

What can I do now to get my app back to live?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your error is caused by [intermittent API failures](https://twitter.com/openshift_ops/status/602088277064187904) on OpenShift, so there is nothing that you can do (except you work for OpenShift).

You can check the [OpenShift Online Status Page](http://status.openshift.com/) to see whether the API errors are still present. To receive the latest status updates you can also follow [OpenShift Operations](https://twitter.com/openshift_ops) on Twitter or join this IRC Channel: `#openshift` on `irc.freenode.net`.

I think the problem will be resolved quickly.

Answer (score 1):

This may be caused by Tomcat running out of memory. Try `rhc app force-stop -a [your_app]` in the [rhc command line tools](https://developers.openshift.com/en/managing-client-tools.html). This should kill all running threads in your app even if it's out of memory. Then, if you want to restart the app, use `rhc app start`.

Source: https://help.openshift.com/hc/en-us/articles/202399040-How-to-restart-an-application-

Comment: I'm not able to `force-stop`, `stop`, `reload`, `start` as well as `app delete`. For all the operations the system states `Unable to perform action on app object. Another operation is already running.`

Comment: Got the same problem. I am also unable to delete my application. I filed a ticket at: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1224429

Comment: Problem seems to be related to OpenShift API. They just tweeted that they have problems: https://twitter.com/openshift_ops/status/602088277064187904